# Auto-fill date function changes the YEAR and not the day

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, formatting

I'm trying to get Google Sheets to auto-fill dates in the beneath cells after I have manually filled one myself. The strange issue is that when I hold Command key and drag down, the cells auto-populate with dates but it is the YEAR that changes, and not the day or month.

I have formatted the column with the day/month/year date pattern. I have tried adding my own custom format to the list but it doesn't allow it. It seems the sheet does recognise it as a date, but isn't understanding that I want the day to increase, not the year.

Comment: Thanks :) I've tried formatting the cells both before and after inputting the data and the same thing occurs. I doubled-checked the sheet's locale was set to UK and it is. The date I'm keying in is 17.12.17.

The only thing I can think is that the use of the fullstops is throwing it off. I'll try slashes and see if that works.

Comment: You can find the [answer here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/151026/117311).

Comment: I had the same problem until I changed the column justification to Right

Answer (score 2):

Just use slash `/` as a separator even thought the format is set to dot `.` separator (date will appear as `dd.mm.yyyy`, but when you will double click to edit, you will see, that data inside is `dd/mm/yyyy`).

Answer (score 1):

First thing: don't hold Command key.

Second: Make sure your computer have the date configured accordingly. If you want to use the date in the format DD/MM/YYYY, you have to set this in your computer.

In my case, if I enter the date in the "wrong" format, let's say: 05/30/2017 (MM/DD/YYYY), when I drag the square down, it updates the year.

Comment: Thanks for replying :) I've checked the date format on my macbook and it is the exact same format I'm trying to employ in Sheets (DD/MM/YY).

Answer (score 0):

- you can use **`ARRAYFORMULA`** instead of dragging it

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&DATEVALUE("2019-1-22")&
                                         ":A"&DATEVALUE("2019-1-29"))), "dd/mm/yyyy")))
  ```

  [image: 0]

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your spreadsheet is set to United Kingdom. File>Spreadsheet Settings>Locale

Comment: Why should it be set to United Kingdom and not to any other country?

Answer (score -1):

make sure your day and month abbreviation is only 3 char (ex Tue vs Tues or Jul vs July) and then select two columns, drag plus symbol across and it should populate your columns by increasing day, date.  [Mon, Jul 1, 2019; Tue, Jul 2, 2019]