# Drag to fill/autocomplete dates only increases year, not day

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

Please see screenshot below. When I dragged on the blue square in highlighted cell, I only get the result below.

I have set correct region in sheet settings. I have set the correct date format in the cells (how do you verify that, it makes no change...)

[image: example]

To set the cell format, I clicked on the column header to select all column rows, then clicked like below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You may set date format for cell, but cell contains text not date value. Check date once more

Answer (score -1):

#### How to fill dates by exactly one year by dragging the cell.

Please do the following:

**First create the second cell and then select and drag BOTH**.

[image]

It has been [asked before](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/112743/117311) but never answered correctly.